# Javascript ternary operator don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/333878/

```
let maxValues = jQuery('#slider').map(function(){
  return this.max;
}).get();
let maxbudget = maxValues.join();
jQuery(document).on('input', '#slider', function() {
  // On récupère la valeur maximal de l'input range
  let value = jQuery(this).val();
  console.log(value);
  // si on utilise la valeur maximale du budget  alors on affiche en plus 'budget de xx€ et au-delà'

  jQuery(this).val() === maxValues.join() ? jQuery('#slider_value').html( jQuery(this).val() + ' € et au-delà') : '';
  jQuery(this).val() < maxValues.join() ? jQuery('#slider_value').text(  jQuery(this).val() + ' €') : '';

  // if ( jQuery(this).val() === maxValues.join()) {
  //   jQuery('#slider_value').html( jQuery(this).val() + ' € et au dela');
  // }
  // else{
  //   jQuery('#slider_value').html( jQuery(this).val() + ' €');
  // }
});
```

3-10k don't work with ternary but if/else work perfecly,What is the problem with my ternary operator ?

Comment: What are you expecting the code to do with those `''` values?

Comment: look the jsfiddle, i just echo the value of range input.

Comment: *"look the jsfiddle"* No. :-) The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) You can do runnable on-site examples using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Answer (score 0):

The way you have those coded, if the condition is false, the statement results in a freestanding empty string (`''`). Since that string isn't assigned to anything and isn't passed into any method, it doesn't have any effect on anything, exactly as though you had coded this:

```
'';
```

(Which is valid code, which may be surprising.)

I'm going to guess you wanted to use `''` as the value to pass to `html` and `text`. If so, you want to put the conditional operator¹ *inside* the arguments:

```
jQuery('#slider_value').html( jQuery(this).val() === maxValues.join() ? jQuery(this).val() + ' € et au-delà' : '');
jQuery('#slider_value').text( jQuery(this).val()  <  maxValues.join() ? jQuery(this).val() + ' €'            : '');
```

---

Side note:

It would probably be a good idea to do `jQuery(this).val()` **once** and store the result in a variable, mostly for clarity, but also because `jQuery(this).val()` does several function calls and such under the covers:

```
var value = jQuery(this).val();
jQuery('#slider_value').html( value === maxValues.join() ? value + ' € et au-delà' : '');
jQuery('#slider_value').text( value  <  maxValues.join() ? value + ' €'            : '');
```

And in fact, on modern browsers, `jQuery(this).val()` can be written `this.value`, even with `select` elements.

---

¹ The correct name of the `? :` operator is the "conditional operator." It's ***a*** ternary operator (an operator accepting three operands), and it's currently the only ternary operator JavaScript has, but who knows, maybe someday another one will be added...

Comment: effectively, I must be tired -_-

Answer (score 0):

> 3-10k don't work with ternary but if/else work perfecly,What is the problem with my ternary operator ?

`jQuery(this).val()` is a string, so `<` does a string comparison. The text below the slider doesn't update when its value is e.g. 3500, because `"3500"` alphabetically (not numerically!) comes after `"30000"`.

(The text isn't updated to `"30000 € et au dela"` either because the value isn't equal to 30000, so the other line also does nothing.)

Comment: oh ok I did not know for the alphabetically order

Answer (score 0):

```
   jQuery(this).val() === maxValues.join() ? jQuery('#slider_value').html( jQuery(this).val() + ' € et au-delà') : jQuery('#slider_value').html( jQuery(this).val() + ' €');;
```

Work